# The application $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} /5\mathbb{Z}$, defined as $\phi(n)= 3n$, is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove or disprove : the application $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}
>  /5\mathbb{Z}$, defined as $\phi(n)= 3n$, is a ring homomorphism.

I think this application is not true because $3n$ couldn't in $\mathbb{Z}
 /5\mathbb{Z}$. We could say $3 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 mod(5)$, so $3n \notin \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.  Is it true? If yes, how is it possible to show that $3n$ couldn't in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Your reasoning is not right, $3n$ is in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ as long as we reduce modulo $5$. For example,

$$ 
\begin{align}
3\cdot 1 &\equiv 3, \\
3\cdot 2 = 6 &\equiv 1, \\
3\cdot 3 = 9 &\equiv 4, \\
& \vdots
\end{align}
$$
are all in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: To prove/disprove that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism you have to check if the axioms hold or otherwise.

Comment: @JoshChen Can you give me a general criterion to say that an element $a$ to be in $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}$. I'm only 13 years old, and I try to learn from myself, but often it is not very obvious.

Comment: It depends on how formal the book/class is - informally, this means the function sending $n\mapsto (3n)+5\mathbb Z\in\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. But it is sloppy notation.

Comment: @JoshChen Technically, $3n\in\mathbb Z$, so it is not in the form $a+5\mathbb Z$, which is the form of the elements of $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, you are right, but can you give me a general criterion to say that an element $a$ to be in $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: An element of $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z$ of the form $a+5\mathbb Z$, where $a$ is an integer. Or, an identical definition, it is a single equivalence class under the equivalence relation $\equiv \pmod 5$ on $\mathbb Z$. @John

Comment: Ok, you are right! So I'll  prove that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Well, don't jump the gun. It might not be a homomorphism - your reasoning was wrong before, but that doesn't mean that it is a ring homomorphism. @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ are the cosets $n + 5\mathbb{Z}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is any integer.
However even though there are infinitely many representatives $n$, there are exactly five of these cosets $n+5\mathbb{Z}$, namely
$$ 0 + 5\mathbb{Z}, 1 + 5\mathbb{Z}, 2 + 5\mathbb{Z}, 3 + 5\mathbb{Z}, 4 + 5\mathbb{Z}.$$
This is because any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ has remainder an integer between $0$ and $4$ on division by $5$, and hence can be written $n = 5a + b$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
Thus
$$n + 5\mathbb{Z} = (b + 5a) + 5\mathbb{Z} = b + 5\mathbb{Z}.$$

All the above is just the formalism behind what we mean when we say that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is the ring of "remainders of $n$ upon division by $5$" consisting of the five "numbers" $0,1,2,3,4$ after reducing modulo $5$.

Comment: This is very clear! So $\phi$ couldn't be a ring homomorphism cause if I take $3,4 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\phi(3 \cdot 4)= 3 \cdot 12 + 5 \mathbb{Z} = 4 + 5\mathbb{Z} \not= \phi(3) \cdot \phi(4) = (3 \cdot 3 + 5\mathbb{Z})(3 \cdot 4 + 5\mathbb{Z}) = 6 + 5\mathbb{Z} = 1 + 5\mathbb{Z}$. In clear, these are not the same equivalence classes, right?

Comment: Yes! Except your values are wrong: $\phi(12) = 3\cdot 12+5\mathbb{Z} = 36 + 5\mathbb{Z} = 1 + 5\mathbb{Z}$ and similarly for $\phi(3)\cdot\phi(4)$.

Comment: I'm making progress! You are very kind to help me, I appreciate it.